# Minimum value of algebraic expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

This is a high school algebra problem,

If the minimum value of the expression $f(a,b) = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 - 10a - 10b +50} +\sqrt{b^2 -4b +20} + \sqrt{a^2 - 14a +74}$ is $k$.

Which occurs at $a = \alpha$, $b = \beta$.
Find the value of $k + 4{\alpha} + 3\beta$

It can be seen that the expression can be written as $f(a,b) = \sqrt{(a-5)^2 + (b-5)^2} + \sqrt{(b-2)^2 + 4^2} + \sqrt{(a-7)^2 + 5^2}$

How do I proceed further from here and could there be a geometric solution?

Comment: @Asher2211 What about the extra constants $+50,+20,+74$ that do not arise from a simple distance formula?

Comment: @FShrike   the are included in the  new form which   one can interpret as distances , or what is your comment?

Comment: The person I replied to deleted their comment, and so my comment is meaningless now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace $a\to n+5$ and $b\to m+5$
Now the expression simplifies to $ \sqrt{n^2 + m^2} + \sqrt{ 4^2+(m+3)^2} + \sqrt{(n-2)^2 + 5^2}$
This is the sum of distance between the following pairs of points

- $(n,0)$ and $(2,5)$
- $(0,m)$ and $(n,0)$
- $(0,m)$ and $(-4,-3)$

If $m\ge0$,
we get $EA>EF$ and $FG+GD>AD$ (refer the following graph). Therefore the path through $A(0,0)$ gives the minimum sum.
[image]
If $m\le0$,
construct $AC$ the angle bisector of reflex $∠EAD$. It is easy to see that $∠EAC$ and $∠CAD$ are obtuse therefore we get $EF+FC>EC>EA$ and $CG+GD>CD>AD$ (refer the following graph). Therefore the path through $A(0,0)$ gives the minimum sum.
[image]

The minimum is obtained when $(n,m)=(0,0)$ i.e. when $a=b=5$.

Comment: Try $(a,b)=(5,5)$.

Comment: Can you write $(a,b)$, for which the minimum occurs? I did not get it.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I have edited it know. The earlier approach was not correct because the shortest distance was not a straight line.